# Hantek DSO2C10 measuring sawtooth wave

Tags: oscilloscope

We recently bought an oscilloscope.

There is no signal generator on it.

I tried to do some tests to make sure that the scope works correctly.

Initially I tried to generate a square wave signal of 8 MHz with Arduino.

```
#ifdef __AVR_ATmega2560__
const byte CLOCKOUT = 11;  // Mega 2560
#else
const byte CLOCKOUT = 9;   // Uno, Duemilanove, etc.
#endif

void setup ()
{
    // 8 MHz timer
    pinMode (CLOCKOUT, OUTPUT);
    TCCR1A = bit (COM1A0);
    TCCR1B = bit (WGM12) | bit (CS10);
    OCR1A =  0;
}

void loop ()
{
    // loop
}
```

[image: Arduino 8MHz signal]

Are the oscillations normal as the square wave rises and falls?

I tried to measure the sawtooth wave from the output of the sound card and without amplification.

The 1 kHz signal seems fine.

[image: Saw tooth 1Khz]

At [5kHz the signal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_VoKro1cIo) is distorted.

[image: Saw tooth 5Khz]

I use the probe with 10x attenuation and it has been calibrated.

Do you see any problem with the device?

Oscilloscope Specs:

- Sampling rate up to 1 GSa/s
- 100 MHz analog channel bandwidth
- 8M memory depth

This time I have done a small experiment. I converted the [5 kHz sawtooth signal](https://bitbucket.org/zayifakimkolu/isaretisleme/raw/4564256c871cf4bf9c3ac86d655079253b177af0/isaret/5kHzdisli.mp3) to mp3. I played it with a sound recorder that was powered by a battery and measured the signal. This time I was hoping to see a perfect signal, but it seems like there is no change.

[image: 1kHz saw tooth]

These sine signals were generated using Python.

This is [10 kHz](https://bitbucket.org/zayifakimkolu/isaretisleme/raw/4564256c871cf4bf9c3ac86d655079253b177af0/isaret/sinus10k.wav).

[image: 10 kHz sine]

[image: 10 kHz sine measurement]

This is [40 kHz](https://bitbucket.org/zayifakimkolu/isaretisleme/raw/4564256c871cf4bf9c3ac86d655079253b177af0/isaret/sinus40k.wav).

[image: 40 kHz sine]

[image: 40 kHz sine measurement]

Does every audio equipment or phone have a cut off frequency?

Comment: Have you tried it with more voltage for the triangle waves? Maybe 500 mV peak-to-peak? Then the noise of the oscilloscope won't be so significant.

Comment: What specs of the scope are of interest? Time-base, voltage-rms, voltage AC, voltage DC, bandwith?

Comment: The "oscillations" are ringing from the parasitic capacitance and inductance of your exact measurement setup.  The biggest influence to that is likely the ground clip and wire.  If your scope has a little metal spring which fits onto the end of the probe, use that instead of the wire+clip and the signal might improve some.  But as for what is being displayed, it looks spot-on given the signal sources and very low signal levels.  Try slower and higher amplitude; that should be much cleaner.

Comment: No, I haven't done that yet. The peak to peak voltage is approximately 300mV. I attempted to amplify the signal with a common emitter.  But it has not yet succeeded.

Comment: @Erdem You should set the probe attenuation setting to 10x as described on page 13 of the [manual](http://hantek.com/uploadpic/hantek/files/20220818/DSO2000%20Series%20Digital%20Storage%20Oscilloscope%20User%20Manual20220818164324.pdf). Note that it also says "When the Attenuation switch is set to 1X, the probe **limits the bandwidth of the oscilloscope to 6MHz**. To use the full bandwidth
of the oscilloscope, be sure to set the switch to 10X."

Comment: @AndrewMorton Probe attenuation switch is set to 10X. Also in the channel menu, it is adjusted to 10X.

Comment: Your 5kHz sawtooth actually looks fine -- it's been low-pass filtered by the sound card, which cuts off around 19-20 kHz.

Comment: @Erdem You are now adding more and different questions to your original question. Yes each audio player has a limit. Otherwise the waveforms would look like staircase signals and the original recorded samples were not representing a staircase. I am surprised any device plays back a 40 kHz sine though, maybe it is intended for bats instead of humans.

Comment: It is Zoom H4N recorder.

Answer (score 1):

What you see could be due to the method the Arduino uses to *generate* the waveforms, due to [ringing](https://incompliancemag.com/article/circuit-theory-model-of-ringing-on-a-transmission-line/) (resonance) in the circuit and/or probes, or, least likely, due to a fault in the oscilloscope. (As @JRE points out, a digitally-created square wave should be better shaped, and the diminishing wiggles are likely due to ringing.)

Microcontrollers do *not* create high-quality waveforms, other than square waves, but [synthesize them from a fundamental and a number of harmonics](https://www.lehman.edu/faculty/dgaranin/Physics_of_Sound/PHY140-Spring-2007-04-Synthesis_and_Analysis_of_complex_waves.pdf). Without filtering, the output is *jagged*.

You might be better served by using a [DIY analog function generator](https://www.electroschematics.com/function-generator/), which can be found as a [kit for ~US$11](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078X9PVX3), or by using a [high-quality commercial waveform generator](https://www.electronicshub.org/best-waveform-generators/). "Not a budget-friendly device," so you might try using it in a school lab.

Also note that connections between signal source and 'scope have to be high-quality, as well (i.e., shielded cable, not random separate wires), and must be [properly terminated](https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/test-measurement/article/21799660/oscilloscope-probes-influence-measurements) (i.e., have the same impedance as the source) to minimize ringing and waveform distortion. You should adjust the compensation of the probe to ensure a good impedance match.

Comment: The square wave is not synthesized.  It is a simple on/off at 8MHz.

Comment: Thanks, @JRE, I'm editing the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

For the 8 MHz square wave generated by  AVR PWM pin, no, the under/overshoots and ringing are not normal, but they appear very easily if everything is not perfect and depends on where the imperfections are, the phenomenon might only be on scope screen because of bad probing technique.

If you do an FFT on a 8 MHz square wave, it basically has fundamental and odd harmonics at 3x,5x,7x,9x, etc. The more you have these harmonics, the better the square wave looks. The faster the edges are, the more you have energy on high harmonics. So you are not really measuring a 8 MHz signal, you are really measuring a signal with lowest frequency of 8 MHz and highest harmonics are beyond the 100 MHz bandwidth of the scope already.

The easiest way to ruin a good scope measurement is to use the probe ground wire with the wire and crocodile clip. For fast transitioning signals with high frequencies, the ground clip just has too much inductance for the signal to be properly referenced to ground at high frequencies. Use the ground spring to reduce the loop area and wire length when probing. For normal purposes and audio bandwidth signals, the ground clip is fine. Also the suggestion is to use the probes in 10x mode to achieve high bandwidth and neverue 1x mode, unless you really know what you are doing and know you need it for some reason.

If the Arduino PWM signal PCB wire is driven hard and the PCB or bypass caps are not able to handle the required bandwidth or current bursts, what you see on scope could really be true and not a probing problem.

For the sound card analog output used as sawtooth generator, basically the same rules apply, the sawtooth output waveform just has different spectrum and audio has lower bandwidth. Sound cards rarely output above 20 kHz, and also the sawtooth needs a lot of harmonics to look like a sawtooth. The quick edge will anyway be limited by the whole system having 20 kHz or so bandwidth, 5 kHz is too high frequency to have enough harmonics to look like sawtooth before the harmonics are cut off at 20 kHz.

Comment: [The oscilloscope probe](http://www.hantek.com/products/detail/73) does not have a ground spring. It comes with only one small piece that is called tip locating sleeve. Is there a way to make a measurement by removing the probe head and connecting a short wire to the ground connection instead of the ground spring?

Comment: @Erdem It's unclear which exact probe model you have but on that web page there are multiple probe models and the metallic ground spring is seen in some pictures.

Comment: It turns out that, the probe, that has photos on the top of the product page is T3100. I think this is a 100x probe. I have PP150. It is a 10x probe.  Metallic ground spring does not appear among the stand accessories list of the product. Instead, it comes with a small piece which is called a tip locating [sleeve] (https://www.lee.org/blog/2019/05/27/what-is-a-locating-sleeve-on-an-oscilloscope/)